# Ninject Binding "all inheriting from x"

Tags: inheritance, binding, ninject, contextual-binding

Pretty usual scenario:

```
public class A { }
public class B:A {}
public class C:A {}
```

I really wonder if it is possible to create Ninject Bindings that resolve all inheriting from A like the following:

```
Bind<A>().ToMethod(ctx => proxyFactory.CreateProxy(ctx.Request.Service) as A);
```

This of course only works for Requests on type A. Requests for B and C are handled the default way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you bind `B` and `C` to `A` and call `GetAll<A>()` or take `IEnumerable<A>` in the constructor?

Comment: In my application A is a ViewModelBase class. Whenever I add new ViewModels, I'd prefer not to have to update the mappings again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a possibility to add [ninject.extensions.conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions), you can bind them dynamically like this:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom<A>()
    .BindBase()
    .Configure(c => c.InTransientScope()));
```